# How to use v-model with nested properties in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have created a form and I'm trying to understand how to use v-model with nested properties in Vue.js

This is the code for my template, as you can see I'm trying to reference the nested properties like so: **form.dobDate**, but how do I reference the properties (**dobDate**, **dobMonth** and **dobYear**) in **mounted** and **watch**? So that whatever I type remains there on page refresh?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form novalidate>
      <b-form-select name="dobDate" id="dobDate" v-model="form.dobDate" :options="optionsDays"></b-form-select>

      <b-form-select name="dobMonth" id="dobMonth" v-model="form.dobMonth" :options="optionsMonths"></b-form-select>

      <b-form-input
        placeholder="Year of Birth"
        required
        autofocus
        class="form-control"
        name="year"
        id="year"
        min="0"
        max="2003"
        type="number"
        v-model="form.dobYear"
      ></b-form-input>

      <input type="text" v-model="name" />

      <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
    </b-form>
    <b-card class="mt-3" header="Form Data Result">
      <pre class="m-0">{{ form }}</pre>
    </b-card>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is script code:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      form: {
        dobDate: {
          selected: ""
        },
        dobMonth: {
          selected: ""
        },
        dobYear: "",
        name: ""
      },
      optionsMonths: [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
      ],
      show: true
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.name) {
      this.name = localStorage.name;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    name(newName) {
      localStorage.name = newName;
    },
    deep: true
  },

  computed: {
    optionsDays() {
      return Array.from(Array(31).keys());
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onSubmit(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.form));
    },
    getDates() {
      return Array.from(Array(31).keys());
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

As you can see I have a form object, with nested properties inside it which I want to bind to, and I'm also using **mounted**() and **watch** to store the data in local storage for when the page refreshes or when submitting the form (no validation at the moment).

Comment: Your code seems correct, what's the issue?

Comment: I want to find out how to reference the properties in the mounted method and when watching, so that the data remains on the page during page refresh or when submitting.

Comment: Not really following. Isn't it just `this.form.dobDate` in `mounted`? For the `watch` you'd need quotes around the property key, `watch: { 'form.dobDate' () {...} }`.

Comment: I tried this, but this doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?:

mounted() {
    if (localStorage.name) {
      this.name = localStorage.name;
      this.form.dobDate = localStorage.form.dobDate;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    name(newName) {
      localStorage.name = newName;
    },
    "form.dobDate"(newDate) {
      localStorage.form.name = newDate;
    },
    deep: true
  },

Comment: `localStorage` allows you to store strings, not objects. You will need to suitably encode them. Some background reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could watch the `form` deeply (accessing its nested field ) and loop through it values using  :

```
  Object.keys(after).forEach(key=>{
          localStorage[key]=after[key]
       })
```

```
 watch: {
    form: {
      handler: function(after, before) {
        Object.keys(after).forEach(key=>{
          localStorage[key]=after[key]
       })
      },
      deep: true
    }
   }
```

Comment: sorry I didn't understand how to use this for the solution, something like this?

watch: {
    form: {
      handler(newval) {
        localStorage = newVal;
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },

Comment: Yes, something like `localStorage.name = newval.name;`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the following:

handler: function(after, before) {
        Object.keys(after).forEach(key => {
          localStorage[key] = after[key];
        });
      },
      deep: true

Comment: you're welcome i edited my answer by explaining it more better