# How can I refactor repetitive conditional Vue.js code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, refactoring, vuex

I have this code in my Vue.js component:

```
mounted() {
    if (localStorage.dobDate) {
      this.form.dobDate = localStorage.dobDate;
    }

    if (localStorage.dobMonth) {
      this.form.dobMonth = localStorage.dobMonth;
    }

    if (localStorage.dobYear) {
      this.form.dobYear = localStorage.dobYear;
    }
  },

  watch: {
    "form.dobDate": {
      handler: function(after, before) {
        localStorage.dobDate = after;
      },
      deep: true
    },
    "form.dobMonth": {
      handler: function(after, before) {
        localStorage.dobMonth = after;
      },
      deep: true
    },
    "form.dobYear": {
      handler: function(after, before) {
        localStorage.dobYear = after;
      },
      deep: true
    }
```

Ask you can see it can get very repetitive, if for example I had a large form, and I don't want to do this for every field. Is there a way I can approach this to make it more DRY? Is there a way I can make it more dynamic for any field in a form for example?

Comment: something like: ['dobDate', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear'].forEach(e => {if (localStorage[e])  console.log(localStorage[e])});.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mounted hook create an array of localStorage fields ["dobDate","dobMonth","dobYear"] and loop  through it using `forEach` method, for each field `localStorage[fieldName]` check if it's defined using [`conditional operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), if it's defined assign it to the correspondant field name in the `form`  data property else pass to the next element:

```
mounted(){
["dobDate","dobMonth","dobYear"].forEach(field=>{

localStorage[field]?this.form[field]=localStorage[field]:{};

})

}
```

In the `watch` property watch the `form` object deeply (watch its nested fields) then loop through its keys by doing the reciprocal operation made in mounted hook :

```
 watch: {
    form: {
      handler: function(after, before) {
        Object.keys(after).forEach(key=>{
          localStorage[key]=after[key]
       })
      },
      deep: true
    }
   }
```

Comment: Great! That worked perfectly, would you mind briefly explaining the code a little just so I have a better understanding of the approach?

Comment: You're welcome, i tried to add some explanation i hope that could help you

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot :)

Comment: you're welcome, i want just know if my answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691501/how-to-use-v-model-with-nested-properties-in-vue-js) helped you or there's some thing to explain?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach with multiple (no deep) watchers.

```
data: {
  form: {},
  dateFields: ['dobDate', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear']
},

mounted() {
  for (const dateField of this.dateFields) {
    if (localStorage[dateField])
      this.$set(this.form, dateField, localStorage[dateField])
  }
},

created() {
  for (const dateField of this.dateFields) {
    this.$watch('form.' + dateField, function(after, before) {
      localStorage[dateField] = after;
    });
  }
}
```

I ignore if it's more or less efficient than only one deep watcher. It may depends on the way your data change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you must have reasons for using localStorage for saving form data in localStorage, so with this code, you can pass the whole form object to localStorage and can retrieve that. in this case, any change in form would make this watch run

```
mounted() {
    if (localStorage.form) {
      this.form = localStorage.form
    }
  },

 watch: {
    "form": {
      handler: function(after, before) {
        localStorage.form = after;
      },
      deep: true
    }
   }
```

Comment: Just tried this but when refreshing the localstorage doesn't seem to work anymore. I also get a lot of errors, such as Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'dobYear' in [object Object]"